# How can I get my App in the similar apps category at google play store?

Tags: android

I have published my [contacts backup app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contactsbackup.cloudstorage.restoredata.contact) at google play store. I have also run campaigns on adwords, But its still not getting any handsome user, I want to be the app in similar apps when anyone explores the relevant apps on play store, any solution, or how the google algos work to get the app in similar apps..

Answer (score 0):

Google uses the information you supply when publishing your app to the Play Store to determine how it will be displayed. If you enlist your app as a productivity app on the play store, then your app is most likely to be displayed to a user who is browsing productivity apps.

Providing a category alone isn't enough for your app to be listed in similar apps section. There is only space for a few apps so Google tries to only list the most popular and apps that are in-demand. The app-ranking algorithm works very similar to the page-ranking algorithm used on Google. Several factors are taken into consideration, a few of which are how many downloads your app have and also how stable it is.